# Anko - alternative to hide one view and show another

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

Should I just initialise and keep both, and set `visibility` to `VISIBLE` or `GONE` depending on the state? Is there a better method? What about memory issues? I would like to have a RecyclerView and a WebView alternately. I want to avoid Fragments - I tried that already and separation of responsibility between Activity, UI and Fragments is a hell.

I keep my UI (inheriting from AnkoComponent) in a separate class, if that matters.

Comment: Any reason not to use a framelayout while changing its content?

Comment: what do you mean?